# How can I extend an existing sharepoint rest api "function"

Tags: 2013, rest

In my project (using SP 2013) I need to get information from a couple of different lists and merge them for display purposes.

Instead of using a couple of ajax requests to the api and merging the data in the js code, can I override the "GetByTitle" function or maybe create a "GetMergedData" that will use the base functionality that the api offers me?

Comment: In that case you have to write your own custom web service

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a custom web service endpoint. I followed [this tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx) to extend the REST api in one of my projects.

Note that you must use the **/_vti_bin/** path to access the endpoint when calling it from an app/add-in, the usual **/_api/** does not allow non-sharepoint endpoints.

Comment: I do not wish to CREATE a custom endpoint, I want to EXTEND an EXISTING one